# Is there a way to send messages from localhost to google [less secure]?

Tags: django, google-chrome, smtp

this question doesn't exist because there is new news about sending messages from Django using localhost to google. I know that to send messages from localhost to google I should launch the "less secure" button in google but it turns out this property is no longer available by google as you can see from the following link: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=profile-less-secure-apps-card

now I need to test my SMTP server if it was working or not by Django and if it was sending a message to google so, How can I accomplish that task by localhost in that case?

Comment: You can create an yahoo account and send emails from there

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Abdin please try to generate an App password from google.[Refer this to  generate App password](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/supportcenter/kb/how-to-create-an-app-password-for-gmail#:%7E:text=Creating%20App%20Passwords%201%20To%20create%20the%20App,option%2C%20click%20over%20it.%20...%20More%20items...%20) and use that App password instead of regular Password.